# bypass the yes prompt in apt-get install, but only authorized packages

Tags: apt, debian, signature

How do I call `apt-get install -y --force-yes` if I want to install the package no matter what, except unauthorized packages.

So I want apt-get to work in non interactive mode and only with signed packages.

Comment: The only time I've ever had to use --force-yes is with unsigned pacakges

Comment: well, i don't need to use --force-yes, i need to make it quite installation and  get only signed packages

Comment: do you mean untrusted packages?

Comment: may add `--assume-yes` dealing with your point.

Comment: I need to install only TRUSTED packages

Comment: What do you mean by "TRUSTED" ?

Comment: by trusted I mean it has signature, and device has public key to check the signature

Comment: Somewhat OT (relevant to Q subject though). `--force-yes` is now deprecated. Instead you should use `--allow-downgrades`, `--allow-remove-essential` and/or `--allow-change-held-packages`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you use one of the options `-y`or `--yes`, or `--assume-yes`

From the man page http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/apt-get.8.html

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>              Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
>              run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
>              changing a held package, **trying to install a unauthenticated
>              package** or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
>              abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

I suppose it may depend on what you mean by "unauthorized packages"

I would use extreme caution with any of the force options with apt-get, forcing things is a good way to break apt, or your install, or both.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need it to force install because it is a signed package surely all you need is

`apt-get install packagename -y`